# How to create a new variable from the result of two selects

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am wanting to get a final price on my cart page from the result of the two selects that are chosen. I am thinking you can create a new variable depending on what is chosen Example - If Type = Canvas and Size = 50x25 a price variable will be $50 and this will be displayed under the price column like so -
**Hopeful results**
[image]

I have done this on my product page to create a price to appear once selects have been choosen however this doesn't create a variable just a placeholder.

```
 jQuery(function($){
     $("select[name='type'], select[name='size']").change(function(){
        var select = $(this);
        var $input = select.parent().find('input');
        if($input.length === 0){
          $input = $('<input>');
        }
        if(select.val() === "" && ""){
            $input.attr({ name: "none", placeholder: "", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
        else if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
            $input.attr({ name:"50x25Canvas" , placeholder: "$150", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc" }).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
        else if(select.val() === "125x125" && "Canvas"){
            $input.attr({ name: "125x125Canvas", placeholder: "$175", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
   });
  });
```

Has anyone got any tips or links to help me learn how to create this thanks for reading!

EDIT 
product page -

```
  <form action="code/add_type.php<?php echo"?id=$photo_id" ?>" method="post">
<select class="form-control" name="type" style="width:25%;" required>
  <option value="">Type</option>
  <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
  <option value="Acrylic">Acrylic</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="size" style="width:25%;" required>
  <option value="">Size</option>
  <option value="50x25">50x25</option>
  <option value="125x125">125x125</option>
</select>
<span class="final_price" name="finalPrice"></span>
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-m' type="submit" style="background-color:black; border-color:black; float: left;">Add to Cart</button>
```

Add type page -

```
$photo_id = $_GET['id'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$qty = $_POST['quantity'];
$price = $_POST['finalPrice'];

$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $type);
$size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $size);
$qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $qty);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $price);

$query="INSERT INTO cart (type, size, qty, p_id, ip_add, price) VALUES ('$type','$size', '1', '$photo_id', '$ip_add', '$price')";
```

Comment: What do you mean with viariable? Do you want a variable containing the price?

Comment: Yes thats what im after

Comment: so `var price = $150` in the second `else if` logic should be enough to set a variable. isn't it?

Comment: btw you are doing jquery select hard/complicated way.

Comment: thanks for the heads up would be much appreciated if you could send some helpful links on how to do it easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that person who has been looking for an answer for days i hope you have stumbled here and found it and not had to spend days looking for this like myself.. i edited my product page to add an id that would receive my jquery variable

```
    <form action="code/add_type.php<?php echo"?id=$photo_id" ?>" method="post">


    <select class="form-control" name="type" style="width:25%;" required>
      <option value="">Type</option>
      <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
      <option value="Framed Print">Framed Print</option>
      <option value="Acrylic">Acrylic</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" name="size" style="width:25%;" required>
      <option value="">Size</option>
      <option value="50x25">50x25</option>
      <option value="125x125">125x125</option>
      <option value="500x250">500x250</option>
    </select>

<div><input id="dyprice" value="" name="price" readonly></div>
    <hr>


    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-m' type="submit" style="background-color:black; border-color:black; float: left;">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

And made changes to my jquery so i could display the finalPrice variable on my page aswell as giving it a different value with each select and the set one Once added to cart would then be sent to my database.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function($){
   $("select[name='type'], select[name='size']").change(function(){
      var finalPrice = "";
      var select = $(this);
      if(select.val() === "" && ""){
          finalPrice = "";
      }else if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
          finalPrice = "150";

      else if(select.val() === "125x125" && "Acrylic"){
        finalPrice = "200";
      }
      else if(select.val() === "Acrylic" && "500x250"){
       finalPrice = "325";
      }
        $('#dyprice').val(finalPrice);
      });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `if` statements do not make sense

```
else if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
```

Then `&& "Canvas"` will *always* be `true` because you do not compare the string with something

**But now for your solution**

```
jQuery(function($){
     $("select[name='type'], select[name='size']").change(function(){
        var finalPrice = 0;
        var select = $(this);
        var $input = select.parent().find('input');
        if($input.length === 0){
          $input = $('<input>');
        }
        if(select.val() === "" && ""){
            finalPrice = 0;
            $input.attr({ name: "none", placeholder: "", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
        else if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
            finalPrice = 150;
            $input.attr({ name:"50x25Canvas" , placeholder: "$150", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc" }).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
        else if(select.val() === "125x125" && "Canvas"){
            finalPrice = 175;
            $input.attr({ name: "125x125Canvas", placeholder: "$175", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
        }
   });
  });
```

Now you got the `finalPrice` variable that you can use further.

In the place where the final price should be shown add a `<span class="final_price"></span>`

If you can't add this span you need to find a html element in that place that you can pick with a jQuery selector like below.

Now you can update the final price with:

```
$('.final_price').html(finalPrice);
```

You most likely want to multiply the `finalPrice` with the quantity first.

Comment: Sorry i did not add the rest in as i didn't want to clog up the screen with non relevant code i much appreciate your answer on creating the variable however how will i get this variable into my database to display the finalPrice in my cart page

Comment: You can create an empty `<span>` at the position of the final price, select this one with jQuery and insert the `finalPrice` there (should be mulitplied by quantity)

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example? I don't quite understand how to do what you have said.

Comment: Edited that into my answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work i need to be able submit a value into my database from this variable through my form action and i can't seem to submit the <span class="final_price"></span> or $('.final_price').html(finalPrice); as for some reason its not picking up its chosen value.. this is what i am currently using .. edit - cant seem to paste new code in there without it being super messy... Have moved into original question

Comment: To do this you need to read into ajax, as you are using jquery anyways i'd suggest you to read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp and this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you should try to use it yourself first, if you have problems ask a new question

Comment: Appreciate your time